# installed ubuntu with windows 8 when booted to ubuntu shows running low with space

Tags: 16.04

Recently I had installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop with Windows 8 and it shows after 3 days of usage that it's "running out of space". Is there something I can do to re-partition my disk? (or any other way?). Please suggest.

Comment: So, what's the output of `df -h`? Please add it to the question.

Comment: yes `gparted` will re-partition your disk, though if its LVM it may not be necessary, so more detail is worthwhile  (mike has asked for diskfree info already).  as gparted doesn't like working on 'active' partitions, use your install-media in 'live' mode to alter partitions.  note: if you move your grub data (step 1.5+) you may need to re-install grub (ie. step1/mbr so it points to correct part of disk [step 1.5], but i'm assuming legacy mode here as I don't know your setup...).  use 'gparted' from your install media!

Comment: ok let me check it and send you all the details

Comment: so this is what I found after Filesystem     ` Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            884M     0  884M   0% /dev
tmpfs           182M  5.8M  176M   4% /run
/dev/sda7       5.9G  5.0G  637M  89% /
tmpfs           906M   13M  894M   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           906M     0  906M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           182M  4.0K  182M   1% /run/user/108
tmpfs           182M   60K  182M   1% /run/user/1000`